# PHPMailer não pegando valor do form

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Então, tenho um form de cadastro de exemplo para testar o PHPMailer, só que o PHP não está aceitando as ID do form apresenta o erro:

> Undefined index

O HTML e o PHP estão logo abaixo:

```php
<?php

//ATENÇÃO ESSE TIPO DE ENVIO SOMENTE PARA USO DO GMAIL
//PARA USOS DE OUTROS DOMINIOS UTILIZA-SE OUTRAS CONFIGURAÇÕES

//pegando valores do FORMULARIO DE CONTATO
$nome       = $_POST ["nome"];
$email      = $_POST ["email"];
$mensagem   = $_POST ["mensagem"];

// Importando as Clases do PHPMailer

include("phpmailer\src\class.phpmailer.php");

require 'phpmailer\src\PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passando "true" para o nova class $mail
try {
    //CONFIGURAÇÕES DO SERVER
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Habilitando
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // setando o  SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Especificando o endereço e o tipo de SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Habilitando
    $mail->Username = 'samuel******4@gmail.com';                 // SMTP e-mail do GMAIL
    $mail->Password = '*********';                           // SENHA DO GMAIL
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Habilitando o tipo de criptografia tls
    $mail->Port = 587;                                      // Conectando a porta TCP   

    //E-MAILS RECIPIENTES
    $mail->setFrom('samuelnicolau044@gmail.com', 'Usuario');  
    $mail->addAddress('$email); 

    //CONTEÚDO
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Setando o e-mail para formato HMTL
    $mail->Subject = 'Teste PHPMailer';
    $mail->Body    = 'Essa é uma Mesangem de Teste <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'O corpo deste e-mail esta em formato HTML';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Mensagem Enviada com Sucesso!';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Mensagem não enviada. Erro: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Teste de envio dos dados </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4 align="center"> Formulário de Contato </h4>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" align="center">
            <br>
            <div>
                <label>NOME</label>
                <input type="text" id="nome">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label>E-MAIL</label>
                <input type="text" id="email">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label>MENSAGEM</label>
            </div>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" id="mensagem"></textarea>
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: obrigado pela atenção, mas não funcionou

Comment: `$mail->addAddress('$email);` tá faltando fechar as aspas simples aqui

Comment: esta dando e-mail invalido

Comment: Então quer dizer que nem precisa das aspas. só a váriavel mesmo

Comment: mesmo assim continua, mas acho que o problema é que não pegando os valores das ID no Formulário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os nome de um `input` passado num POST é definido pelo atributo **name** e não pelo atributo `id`.

O atributo `id` é um identificador dentro do documento, porém este identificador não é enviado em requisições, mas sim o atributo **name** e seu valor (**value**).

Então teus inputs mudariam de:

```
 <input type="text" id="nome">
```

para:

```
 <input type="text" name="nome">
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Funcionou !!

Comment: Por nada. Não esqueça que não é necessário retirar os `id`, os dois campos podem coexistir e ter o mesmo valor se necessário.

Answer (score 2):

### Correções

Do jeito que estava, não iria funcionar por causa do espaço, pois `$_POST` é um *Array* e dessa forma está errada: `$_POST ["nome"];`

Para corrigir troquei por `filter_input` assim ajuda contra SQL Injection:

```
$nome = filter_input(POST, 'nome');
```

Adicionei as propriedades a mais no `SMTP`, pois dependendo do seu servidor, poderá evitar certos erros:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )   
);
```

Comentei a linha `# $mail->AltBody = 'O corpo ...';` pois como está usando `$mail->isHTML(true);` então só irá precisar do `$mail->Body`.

Contrário do que está escrito `O corpo deste e-mail esta em formato HTML`, seria "...**NÃO** está em HTML".

E na parte do **HTML**, estava faltando o atributo `name` em seus `inputs`, corrigindo ficando:

```
<input type="text" name="nome">
<input type="text" name="email">
<textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="mensagem">
```

*como dito pelo @fernandosavio, poderá manter também o atributo `id`, caso utilize, se não, melhor tirar já que não tem utilidade.

---

#### Script final

```
$nome     = filter_input(POST, 'nome');
$email    = filter_input(POST, 'email');
$mensagem = filter_input(POST, 'mensagem');

include 'phpmailer\src\class.phpmailer.php';
require 'phpmailer\src\PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';    
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )    
    );
    $mail->Username = 'samuel******4@gmail.com';    
    $mail->Password = '*********';               
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->setFrom('samuelnicolau044@gmail.com', 'Usuario');  
    $mail->addAddress('$email'); 

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Teste PHPMailer';
    $mail->Body    = 'Essa é uma Mesangem de Teste <b>in bold!</b>';
    # $mail->AltBody = 'O corpo deste e-mail esta em formato HTML';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Mensagem Enviada com Sucesso!';

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo 'Mensagem não enviada. Erro: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Teste de envio dos dados </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4 align="center"> Formulário de Contato </h4>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" align="center">
            <br>
            <div>
                <label>NOME</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label>E-MAIL</label>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label>MENSAGEM</label>
            </div>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="mensagem"></textarea>
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado troquei o Código e mudei o que o fernandosavio falou e funcionou Perfeitamente

Comment: @SamuelNicolau Por nada! .... Mas por regras do site, não é necessário agradecer. O seu voto na resposta já seria para essa finalidade. Não esqueça de marcar uma resposta para finalizar a pergunta! ✌️

Comment: estou ciente agora!